# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Функция делает запрос на авторизацию пользователя и, если нет никакой ошибки, делает роутинг на главную страницу. Почему здесь я получаю такую ошибку?

```js
const submitData = async () => {
 try {
   await props.authUser(formData)
   props.history.push(routesMap.home);
 }
}
```

Comment: по одной функции запроса ничего не скажешь, нужно полностью смотреть компонент. воспроизведите ошибку в какой нибудь песочнице и выложите сюда ссылку

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает когда setState происходит в асинхронной функции, которая выполняется уже после срабатывания роута

Comment: Здесь thunk асинхронная, которая и диспатчит state, но я же дожидаюсь ее выполнения с помощью await

Comment: @Nikita не обязательно здесь. Например при старте компонента в componentDidMount некий ajax запрос, у которого при onSuccess происходит setState. Ответ на этот запрос приходит позже перехода по роуту и пытается сделать setState уже на размонтированном компоненте.

Comment: А ведь не очень хорошо, если у менят submitData вне useEffect или DidMount?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, вы, видимо, на 100% правы. Я делаю роут на home, а само приложение при старте запрашивает продукты, которые и рендерит home. Видать, роут на него же все ломает) Я хотел сделаьт так, что сначало запроси продукты then рендери все приложение, но так и не придумал, как это сделать)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, вы не могли бы подсказать, а как сделать так, чтобы роутинг был после setstate?

Comment: @Nikita второй параметр у setState - это коллбэк, который выполнится после изменения состояния. В нем можно указать нужные функции

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, а в случае redux?Там никакого setState нет